# How to define the correct pattern/expression in python?

Tags: python, split, expression

Hi i want to add a split after "September 10, 2017" in the following scentence "September 10, 2017 Kochkurs im Hiltl". I defined the pattern of September 10, 2017 as followed: `pattern = r"\W+\s+\d+\,\s+\d+\s+"` However, this is wrong. Do you know why? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem with this pattern is that `\W` matches anything other than a letter, digit or underscore (e.g. matches a non-word). You can replace it with `\w`, that matches a word character:

```py
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"\W+\s+\d+\,\s+\d+\s+")
print(pattern.search("September 10, 2017 Kochkurs im Hiltl"))
# Output: None

pattern = re.compile(r"\w+\s+\d+\,\s+\d+\s+")
print(pattern.search("September 10, 2017 Kochkurs im Hiltl"))
# Output: <re.Match object; span=(0, 19), match='September 10, 2017 '>
```

Comment: @NicoleBrühwiler Glad to help! If my answer helped you, you can accept it by clicking on the big checkmark to select it as the accepted answer, so people answering can focus on older questions which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because of the use of \W

Following works as you expected:

```
s = "September 10, 2017 Kochkurs im Hiltl"
date_str = list(filter(bool, re.split("^(\S+\s+\d+\,\s+\d+)", s)))[0]
print(date_str)
```